# Align custom SVG button with text below in Bootstrap 5 Card

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-5

I am trying to align custom buttons 3 wide inside a bootstrap card. I want the buttons to wrap to next row to 2 wide on small screens. Also I cannot get the text to center properly below the buttons. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Here is what I have so far.
[image]

```css
.quick-link-btn {
        padding: 10px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid #fbeced;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        fill: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #fbeced;
    }

    .quick-link-btn svg {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        stroke-width: 1.5;
        color: #e7515a;
    }
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <h5 class="card-title mb-3">Quick Links</h5>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Time Clock</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Button 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Button 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Button 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Button 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <a class="quick-link-btn" href="javascript:void0">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock">
          <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
          <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </a>
      <div>Button 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you may do `a+div{width:80px; text-align:center}` where 80px = 60px (like the width of the a element) + 10px * 2 (like the padding of the a element)

Answer (score 1):

To have two columns on small screens, you need to add the appropriate classes:

```
col-6 col-sm-4
```

Here full example

```css
.quick-link-btn {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #fbeced;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    fill: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fbeced;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.quick-link-btn svg {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
    color: #e7515a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-3">Quick Links</h5>
                    
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time Clock</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time Clock</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time Clock</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time Clock</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 d-flex justify-content-center" style="text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn quick-link-btn">
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-clock"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline></svg> 
                                </a>
                                <p>Time Clock</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

justify-content-center is now added to each column, and that the content of each column is wrapped in a div, since both text-to-image and image-to-text alignment needs to be aligned.
You also don't need to add rows for every 3 columns. Since on a small screen a row should have 2 columns per row. All columns are added to one row. Width of every column will be regulate of classes col-6 col-sm-4

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your HTML with a native Web Component

`<time-button>label</time-button>`

Optionally using shadowDOM so inner CSS can be small and no global CSS will destroy shadowDOM content

```js
customElements.define("time-button", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor(){
    super().attachShadow({mode:"open"})
           .innerHTML = `<style>
              :host { display:inline-block; --w:60px }
              div {
                  padding: 10px;
                  border-radius: 8px;
                  cursor: pointer;
                  width: var(--w);
                  height: var(--w);
                  background: #fbeced;
              }
              svg { width:100%; color:#e7515a }   
              h4  { margin-block-start:.5em; text-align:center;font: 12px arial }
           </style>
          <div>
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" 
                 stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
              <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
              <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
            </svg>
            <h4><slot>LABEL</slot></h4>
          </div>`;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    this.onclick = (evt) => {
      alert( this.innerHTML );
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<time-button>Time Clock</time-button>
<time-button>Button1</time-button>
<time-button>Button2</time-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help, I used a few things from each of you.
Below is code.

```
.quick-link-box { 
    display:inline-block; 
    --w:80px 
}
.quick-link {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: var(--w);
    height: var(--w);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.quick-link svg { 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    stroke-width: 1.5;
}

.quick-link-box h4  { 
    white-space: nowrap !important; 
    margin-block-start:.5em; 
    text-align:center;
    font: 12px arial;
}

.quick-link:hover {
    background-color: #eaeaec;
}

.quick-link:hover svg {
    color: grey;

}

.ql-primary {
    background-color: #eceffe;
}
.ql-primary svg{
    color: #4361ee;
}
.ql-info {
    background-color: #e6f4ff;
}
.ql-info svg{
    color: #2196f3;
}
.ql-success {
    background-color: #ddf5f0;
}
.ql-success svg {
    color: #00ab55;
}
.ql-warning {
    background-color: #fcf5e9;
}
.ql-warning svg {
    color: #eab764;
}
.ql-secondary {
    background-color: #f2eafa;
}
.ql-secondary svg {
    color: #805dca;
}
.ql-danger {
    background: #fbeced;
}
.ql-danger svg {
    color:#e7515a;
}

 <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title mb-3">Quick Links</h5>
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4 text-center mb-3">
                    <div class="quick-link-box">
                        <a href="{{ route('timeclock.index') }}">
                            <div class="quick-link ql-danger">
                                <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                    fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
                                    <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
                                    <polyline points="12 6 12 12 16 14"></polyline>
                                    </svg>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <h4 class="text-muted">Time Clock</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And the Result:
[image: Final Result]