# How to use an SVG file for the shape of my text buttons?

Tags: svg, button, css-variables

I'm setting up a design system in NextJS14 (React). We are using CSS modules and have all colors stored in CSS variables (custom properties).

We have these nice-looking buttons in our Figma design. I want to use the exported SVG for the shape of our text buttons. [preview of custom button shape svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbfkE.png)

I made some progress by setting the `background-image:` to the url of the SVG. However, I have not found a way to **dynamically change the fill and stroke colors of the SVG** based on the props passed into the custom Button component.

Comment: That's not going to be possible if you use background-image

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, then I won't struggle down that path any further!

I'm very open to exploring other ways of solving this problem. Suggestions @RobertLongson?

Comment: In general, are alle the buttons in one color like the one you like to or are there any with more colors?

Comment: Don't use an IMG or background-image; use a Web Component [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648918/align-custom-svg-button-with-text-below-in-bootstrap-5-card/76649300#76649300), but you will  need some extra time to make standard Web Components work in React, because React only supports the modern JS standard [for 67%](https://custom-elements-everywhere.com/) (down from 71%)

Comment: @chrwahl - All svg buttons have a linear gradient fill (with just two hex colors) and a mono-color stroke.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman - I was also thinking of defining the svg directly in the React <Button> component, as that allows to dynamically change the colors with JS. However, I don't know how to link to the colors stored in our CSS variables directly from JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some options. In your case I guess that the first two examples could be used. The last one is an alternative approach that only works in some cases.

##### Embed the SVG

Embed the SVG into the HTML and style the SVG elements using CSS.

```css
button.orange rect {
  fill: orange;
}

button.lime rect {
  fill: lime;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
}

button svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

button span {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1; 
  align-self: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="orange">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 20">
    <rect width="60" height="20" rx="5" fill="white" />  
  </svg>
  <span>Button</span>
</button>

<button class="lime">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 20">
    <rect width="60" height="20" rx="5" fill="white" />  
  </svg>
  <span>Button</span>
</button>
```

##### CSS background-image

Just repeat creating different CSS selectors with different background images.

```css
button.orange {
  fill: orange;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 20"><rect width="60" height="20" rx="5" fill="orange" /></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

button.lime {
  fill: orange;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60 20"><rect width="60" height="20" rx="5" fill="lime" /></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
}

button svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

button span {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1; 
  align-self: center;
  padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="orange">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>

<button class="lime">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>
```

##### CSS backgrounds with gradients only

Combine a background image (the SVG document) with a solid background color defined in CSS. The SVG image is just a gradient going from transparent to white.

```css
button.gradient01 {
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgogIDxkZWZzPgogICAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJnMDEiIGdyYWRpZW50VHJhbnNmb3JtPSJyb3RhdGUoOTApIj4KICAgICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwIiBzdG9wLWNvbG9yPSJ3aGl0ZSIgLz4KICAgICAgPHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIxMDAlIiBzdG9wLW9wYWNpdHk9IjEiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IndoaXRlIiAvPgogICAgPC9saW5lYXJHcmFkaWVudD4KICA8L2RlZnM+CiAgPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNnMDEpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}

button.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

button.lime {
  background-color: lime;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  display: grid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button svg {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

button span {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1; 
  align-self: center;
  padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

```html
<button class="orange gradient01">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>

<button class="lime gradient01">
  <span>Button</span>
</button>

<p>The SVG used as background:</p> 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g01" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g01)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and code examples @chrwahl! Much appreciated! I'm still experimenting with the different approaches. And trying to fully understand how/when they work in relation to my project. Will get back to you when I'm there!

Answer (score 0):

[End result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deb38.png)

I'm thrilled to share that I finally got it working to:

- Use an SVG for the shape of my button
- Change the scaling, width, colors and optional icons with props
- Have the colors linked to my custom CSS variables for maintainability

I could not have gotten to this point without your suggestions @chrwahl. Thanks a million!

Comment: Words are understood differently. Please provide the code for your solution. And I'm sure it will be positively appreciated